# Naming a [0, 1] range datatype?

Tags: c++, embedded, naming

In our project we have a datatype that is constrained to all float values between 0 and 1 (including 0 and 1). How could such a datatype be named?

This datatype is used for DAC and ADC abstraction. I.e. we don't care about how many bits the DAC or ADC supports, we just take this [0, 1]-datatype and multiply with the respective max value.

Comment: what are you using it for? "unit_intervall" ?

Comment: How about Fractional?

Comment: Is there a real need to give it a real name of its own? I'd tend toward just `InclusiveInterval{0.0, 1.0}`

Answer (score 1):

Well I don't know your context so there's probably a better option, but from what you say it looks like a "UnitInterval".

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).